Bindig SQL query columns to custom DBGrid columns

Is it possible to display columns from the database in manually created DBGrid columns?
I am using Delphi 11 and this is my SQL query:
procedure TProizvodiForm.LoadProducts;
begin

      with DB.ZQuerySelect do
        begin
          Active := false;
          sql.Clear;
          sql.Text := 'SELECT productid as ID, ' +
                      'name as Product, ' +
                      'code as Code, ' +
                      'manufname as Manufacturer, ' +
                      'unitname as Unit FROM product';
          Active := true;
        end;    
end;

I create columns in grid

Note: I know I can just use query to display the result in DBGrid without creating columns. By creating columns, I have the possibility to adjust the width of each column and to change the names and headers.

The DBGrid's DataSource and the TColummn's FieldName determine what data is shown.
